# ¿Cómo estilizar ciertas celdas con Kable?

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo el sigueinte data frame

```
datafr <- structure(c(0.475, 0.525, 0.451, 0.475, 0.459, 0.559, 0.425, 0.511, 
                      0.522, 0.4, 0.453, 0.375, 0.556, 0.425, 0.534, 0.475, 0.413, 0.45, 0.375, 
                      0.535, 0.425), .Dim = c(7L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("colA", 
                                                                               "colB", "colC")))
```

y con la libreria Kable requiero que se marque en color rojo SOLO el valor maximo por fila.

Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Una forma simple con R base, podría ser:

```
tabla <- apply(datafr, 1, function(x) cell_spec(x, color = ifelse(x == max(x), "red"," black")))
tabla <- t(tabla)
tabla <- as.data.frame(tabla)
tabla <- setNames(tabla, colnames(datafr))
tabla <- kable(tabla, escape = F)
kable_styling(tabla)
```

Básicamente con `apply()` y `cell_spec()`, calculamos el máximo por fila y le damos los atributos de color cuando alguna celda coincide con el máximo.

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias! ¿Cómo puedo hacer para conservar el nombre de las columnas?

Comment: Chequea mi última edición. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias ! Sos un genio

Comment: @Andres si esto responde a tu pregunta, podés aceptarla haciendo click en el tilde debajo de las flechas de votación